# Flutter Web - Call to Google Analytics API "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I am trying to connect the Google Analytics API to my Flutter Web application. To make sure my request goes through, I'm using Google's oAuthPlayGround: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

I have successfully activated the API on the Google Play Console, retrieve the client_id and client_secret that I sent to the API. So I get the oAuth Token successfully. However, when I try to call any endpoint, I get a 403 error: "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."

After checking, I am indeed an administrator on Google Analytics and an owner on Firebase.

Any ideas ?

- Successfully activated the API on Play Console
- Create oAuth IDs on Play Console
- Be administrator on Google Analytics
- Be owner on Firebase

Error message :

{
"error": {
"message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
"code": 403,
"errors": [
{
"reason": "insufficientPermissions",
"message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
"domain": "global"
}
]
}
}

Thanks by advance,